# iOS5 UINavigationBar background image issues when prompt is shown

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am using the new appearance proxy in iOS 5 to style my UINavigationBar with a background image.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ZSNavigationBG.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ZSNavigationLandscapeBG.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

This works fine, but I need to set the prompt property of the nav bar. When I do that, the height of the nav bar increases, and my background image no longer fills that nav bar vertically, so it looks very bad.

How can I account for the height change with a prompt when using a custom background image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image should be a [stretchable image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth%3atopCapHeight%3a) so it can extend in either direction without breaking anything.

Comment: The stretchable image method has been deprecated. Use [resizeable image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW50) instead.