# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController "Groups" View Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, abpeoplepickerview

I'm using a custom Navigation Bar appearance in my app with this code in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

However, this appearance breaks when I present an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` (to allow selection of a contact to populate the To: field for a new email), because the system uses an extra tall `UINavigationBar` when this view is showing due to the `prompt` property on `UINavigationItem` being set by the system ("Choose a contact to mail").

The fix is to add this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Fixed view of contacts list]

However, this little hack doesn't work when you tap the **Groups** button from the initial view. It still looks broken due to the extra tall Navigation Bar:

[image: Broken view of extra tall Navigation Bar after tapping Groups button]

Any ideas what the controller name is for that view (so I can apply the same exclusion as above), or another way to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350976/ios5-uinavigationbar-background-image-issues-when-prompt-is-shown

Looks like one way to solve this is to use a resizable image for the background of the navigation bar. I swear I tried this and it didn't work...will have to try again. But this isn't an option if the background image is a smooth linear gradient (as in my case) -- there's no way to have the system resize/stretch the image and retain the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just hitting this now.. any luck resolving? I'm thinking to try interating through the ABPeoplepickerNavigationControllers view controllers and applying appearanceWhenContainedIn method...

Comment: Still unresolved, though I have given up on this for now. Let me know if you can figure anything out!!

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with this as well, but think I've pieced together a solution.

The group selection view is some other (unknown to me, likely private) class, so we can't specify an exception style through an appearance-proxy-when-contained-in approach, as you've done for the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. Instead, we should try and resolve the original issue, which is the custom background image not rendering properly when the prompt is shown and the navigation bar is tall.

The solution here ([iOS5 UINavigationBar background image issues when prompt is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350976/ios5-uinavigationbar-background-image-issues-when-prompt-is-shown)) suggests using a resizable background image for the navigation bar.

That almost worked for me, but the background image I was using included the shadow for underneath the navigation bar and that wasn't resizing correctly when the prompt was shown. Instead, I had to use a resizable background image without a shadow and then specify the shadow image separately.

```
UINavigationBar* navigationBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBarBackgroundNoShadow"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, 3, 0)]
                forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBarShadowResize"]];
```

Using this approach removed the need for any exception styling and looked good in both the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and the group selection view, as well as at standard height.